# Emgucv frame capture when moving on video

Tags: video, frame, emgucv, capture

sorry for my English, I want to get frame capture when moving on loaded video, how can I do it? Example, there is a way, take a frame capture while the car is on the way, but, don't take a frame capture while the road is empty.
my codes are as follows;

```cs
      VideoCapture capture = null;
      List<Mat> image_array = new List<Mat>();
    
            private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
            {
            Mat frame = new Mat();
            capture.Retrieve(frame, 0);
            ımageBox1.Image = frame;
            Thread.Sleep((int)capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.Fps));
            try
            {
                string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss_ffff");
                frame = capture.QueryFrame();
                Bitmap captureBitmap = new Bitmap(frame.Bitmap);
                captureBitmap.Save(@"D:\FrameCapture\Capture-" + time + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                if (frame != null)
                {
                    image_array.Add(frame);
                }
                else
                {
                    Application.Idle -= ProcessFrame;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
```

I want something like this;

```cs
    if(moved)
    {
    captureBitmap.Save(......)
    }
```

how can I do it?